# Is there any required div wrapper inside a React component

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I create a menu using React JS:

```
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Title />
      <OptionsDropdown />
    );
  }
});
```

where Title and OptionsDropdown are other React classes.
The problem is this code has error until I wrap them around a div like :

```
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div class="something">
        <Title />
        <OptionsDropdown />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Is there anyway better to handle this situation when I want no div is wrapped outside Title and OptionsDropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Finally. I found out there is maximum one root node in render function in React JS. Better to wrap it with a div.